# How can I align these vertices on a particular axis?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, edges, knife-tool

I need these vertices aligned on the X axis but I'm not sure how... I'm doing this to duplicate a cut I made on one side of a building to another with knife project... The screenshot is shown below:

[image: Vertices needing alignment]

[image: Other side of knife tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select one vertex which has the correct X location and press Shift S > Cursor to selected.

Switch the pivot point to 3D cursor.

Select all vertices of the arc and press S, X, 0, Enter.

[image]